# Parse a string containing html using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Astounded this question didn't show up in the related questions list. There's some similar stuff, but I'd like to know:

```
string s = "<p>Cats</p><div id='fishbiscuits'>myValue</div>";
```

I want to use JQuery to get myValue.

How can I do this?

Comment: `string s =` should be `var s =`...

Comment: +1 just for making us search for `fishbiscuits`....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the jQuery function to create the objects and then you can use it like you would any other collection of elements.  Any of these should work just fine:

```
// Using filter()
$(s).filter("#fishbiscuits").text();

// Wrapping with a div and using find()
$('<div>' + s + '</div>').find("#fishbiscuits").text();

// Wrapping with a div and using selector context
$('#fishbiscuits', '<div>' + s + '</div>').text();

// Creating a div, setting the html and then using find
$('<div>').html(s).find("#fishbiscuits").text();
```

Comment: although since `#fishbiscuits` is at the "root" of that document, you'll need to `.filter()` instead of `.find()`, or wrap `s` up in another element like: `$('<div>'+s+'</div>').find("#fishbiscuits").text()`

Comment: @SLC: see my edit, @gnarf: thanks for the correction, when I originally read the question I thought it was already wrapped.

Comment: Another Idea: `$('<div/>').html(s).find('#fishbiscuits').text();`

Comment: Another Idea: `$(s).siblings('#fishbiscuits').text();`

Comment: @All: added a bunch of options :-)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the info provided, this should do the trick:

```
var s = "<p>Cats</p><div id='fishbiscuits'>myValue</div>";
var dummyElement = $( '<div>' + s + '</div>' );
var yourString = $( '#fishbiscuits', dummyElement ).html ();
```

It basicly creats a new DOM element containing the HTML in your string, then searches for the element with the id 'fishbiscuits' and returns it's inner HTML

Comment: No clue, solid solution... other than the missing `$` on the third line :)... Also, personally I think `dummyElement.find('#fishbiscuits')` is a little easier to read than `$('#fishbiscuits',dummyElement)`